# Let $x_n$ be the sequence whose nth element is the nth digit of $\sqrt 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Then $x_0=1, x_1=4, x_2=1, x_3=4$, etc.

(a) Prove the limit does not exist as $n$ approaches infinity.

(b) Prove $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Surely you have thought about this a bit. Please share.

Comment: Hint for (a): assume otherwise, and consider $\epsilon < 1/2$.

Comment: Hint for (b): Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem

Answer (score 2):

Outline:

(1) If the limit existed, then the $n$-th digit of $\sqrt{2}$ would be eventually constant, contradicting the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

(2) Some digit must occur infinitely often.

Comment: (2) Some _two_ digits, at least.

Comment: Yes, but we only need one for a convergent  subsequence.